# Pre-built binaries for BoringCrypto Android?

Tags: android, cryptography, android-ndk, fips, boringssl

Section 12.1 of the [BoringCrypto Android FIPS 140-2 Security Policy](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/documents/security-policies/140sp3753.pdf) gives instructions for building BoringCrypto Android from source.

**Are these binaries distributed anywhere so I don't need to build from source?**

Comment: Related: https://developers.google.com/tink/FIPS